# virtualenv hanging forever pythonanywhere

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/) to get a django application up on pythonanywhere, but when trying to create a virtual environment using

```
 virtualenv --python=python3.5 myvenv
```

The console hangs

I have done this before a while ago and I remember it was all quite painless but when running this command the console is just hanging and I eventually get put in the tarpit. When I interrupt the process I get some errors around Python 2.7

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 myvenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/username/myvenv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/username/myvenv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 669, in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise SystemExit(popen.wait())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2327, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1376, in wait
pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 767, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Not sure if these relate to anything or if they are just because the interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

General practice is to reference the python binary directly, run virtualenv as a module, and specify the directory in which to place the virtualenv. For your example above:

```
/path/to/python/bin/python3.5 -m virtualenv myvenv
```

This will create the virtual environment in myvenv, running python3.5. Note: your base install of python3.5 must have virtualenv library installed (either through pip or source).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this it did use python 3.5 but is still hanging

Comment: Is there a difference in the stack trace?

Comment: You should not use just `python3.5`. you need to use either `which python3.5` or as mentioned in the answer,  `virtualenv --python=/path/to/python/bin/python3.5 myvenv`

Comment: @Lekic Yes, on interrupt I get the same stack trace except rather than mentioning python 2.7 it mentions python 3.5.

Comment: @conrad trying your command I get the same results as in the question

Comment: How long does it hang? Do you see any output while it runs?

Comment: @Lekic, it hangs forever. I get to "installing setuptools, pip, wheel.."
The errors I am getting in the question occur when I interrupt the process

Comment: Are you in the tarpit on PythonAnywhere? That would slow the install process down.

Comment: @Glenn, I don't start off in the tarpit but after some time that the process is running I am put into the tar pit

Comment: It's possible that you're just interrupting it too soon.

Comment: I was under the same impression as @Glenn. Can you try leave it for a ridiculous time (say, 10 mins)? It shouldn't take more than 1, but for arguments sake.

Comment: @Glenn, I was running this hours at a time without interrupt but it still didn't work.

Comment: I solved my tarpit problems with a tip from the pythonanywhere forum: 'If you go to the consoles tab, you could hit the fetch all processes button and kill all jupyter (in my case mysql) related processes if you are not using notebooks right now'. Other forum entries did no help. I add here to make it easier to find